# Redirect to old site when connecting new prestashop install to old database

Tags: prestashop

I created a sub-domain and installed fresh prestashop.

Then i edited settings.inc file of the new prestashop install and i changed database info to old database settings.

```
define('_DB_SERVER_', 'localhost');
define('_DB_NAME_', 'olddatabse');
define('_DB_USER_', 'dbuser');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', 'dbpass');
define('_DB_PREFIX_', 'ps_');
define('_MYSQL_ENGINE_', 'InnoDB');
define('_PS_CACHING_SYSTEM_', 'CacheMemcache');
define('_PS_CACHE_ENABLED_', '0');
define('_MEDIA_SERVER_1_', '');
define('_MEDIA_SERVER_2_', '');
define('_MEDIA_SERVER_3_', '');
define('_COOKIE_KEY_', '********');
define('_COOKIE_IV_', 'LU3nff3f');
define('_PS_CREATION_DATE_', '2014-08-05');
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    define('_PS_VERSION_', '1.6.0.9');
define('_RIJNDAEL_KEY_', '********');
define('_RIJNDAEL_IV_', '******');
```

Normally old presta is installed on mydomain.com and i created demo.mydomain.com but when i enter the demo.mydomain.com it redirects to mydomain.com

How to stop redirection and use old database with the new prestashop install ?

Answer (score 1):

In the old database modify `domain` and `domain_ssl` fields to `demo.mydomain.com` in the `ps_shop_url` table. However then `mydomain.com` will redirect to `demo.mydomain.com`. PrestaShop always redirects to the shop domain.